# Java Selenium error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, classnotfoundexception

I use Java with Selenium (in general I use ChromeDriver) with Eclipse IDE and I get an error when I try to run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at crawler.House.getRooms(House.java:166)
    at model.Main.main(Main.java:258)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.HasAuthentication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 26 more
```

The Selenium is imported with Maven, here is my pom.xml file (for project A):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>licenta-crawling</groupId>
  <artifactId>licenta-crawling</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-1</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What should I do? In another project (let's say project B), the same block of code from project A works perfect, without errors, here is a pom.xml file for project B:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpellChecker</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpellChecker</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>

    
    
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
       <version>1.13.1</version>
  </dependency>
    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    
 
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
 
 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha5</version>
    </dependency>
        
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>24.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
 
 
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The version for dependencies selenium-java and htmlunit-driver are the same (in project A and project B), and I don't think that the extra dependencies from project B affect the result. I tried to search for similar question but I didn't find a solution, also I didn't find a question with contains error about HasAuthentication.

Comment: Are you using same URL in project A and B?

Comment: By URL you mean the URL for chrome driver (the URL for the page which will be load)? Yes, it its the same URL, but project A got the error from start, he didn't reach to open the simulated browser, the problem begin when I use driver.get(url)

Comment: As per Selenium API doc's.. if website requires any authentication through URL then this error occurs. Please refer https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication.html

Answer (score 4):

With selenium 4 I had to add `selenium-api` as dependency. Seems the class resides in this package.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Selenium 4 on SpringBoot + Gradle project.
Downgrade of Selenium dependancy to 3.141.59 helped. Hope thats an option for you.

Gradle dependancies:

```
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.141.59'
```